# Regulated Cascode TIA using a voltage amplifier with negative gain

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, amplifier, circuit-design, integrated-circuit

I am reading [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9123614) article.
Why in the article is it said that the v_sg increase when vx increases?
well, why does it use v_sg instead of v_gs for NMOS in the first place?

As I see it, VY must be larger than VX to keep M1 and M3 in saturation.
So, when VX increases --> VY decreases --> v_gs M1 decreases --> ID M1 decreases.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Notice that *Δv* is an **AC** signal, a small-signal voltage component at the gate of M<sub>1</sub>. Accordingly, all the other small-letter signals (*-AΔv* etc.). Whereas in your analysis ("VY must be larger than VX to keep M1 and M3 in saturation. So, when VX increases --> VY decreases --> v_gs M1 decreases --> ID M1 decreases"), you are talking mostly about **DC** signals (VX, VY, ID), occasionally mixing DC with AC (v_gs).

You carry out the DC analysis to find out the quiescent points of non-linear devices (transistor, diodes). To calculate linear parameters of your circuits (gains, input/output impedances, etc.), you perform AC analysis in **small-signal approximation**.